# Why would Jest test randomly fail if not in watch mode?

Tags: jestjs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm having a weird problem. If I run

```
jest --watch
```

via npm, everything works as expected.

If I turn on coverage, then I get random errors, mostly like this

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat
```

### More details

The command that is reliable is defined in `package.json` as:

```
"test": "jest --watch --config jest-watch.json",
```

The command that is not reliable is

```
"test-all": "jest"
```

We use a `jest.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: false,
  testURL: 'http://localhost/',
  coverageReporters: ['json', 'lcov', 'html'],
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/src/**/*.{js,jsx}',
    '!**/node_modules/**',
    '!**/vendor/**',
    '!**/coverage/**',
    '!<rootDir>/lambda.js',
    '!<rootDir>/server.js'
  ],
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      statements: 40,
      branches: 17,
      functions: 18,
      lines: 41
    }
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setupTests.js'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/lambda.js', '<rootDir>/server.js']
};
```

and the `jest-watch.config' file is:

```
{
  "collectCoverage": false,
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>/setupTests.js"]
}
```

This is happening in every project I use jest, both node and react apps. However, I have about 10+ teammates, some on Windows and some on Macs and nobody else is having this problem. I believe I'm the only one using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).

I'm running Windows 10 1803. I'm using Ubuntu as my Linux distro.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't test it, but your configuration looks fine, I've some question:

1- Do you use jest Global or local in your project?
2- What happened when you run inside the project folder "npm run test"?
3- have you tried to run "jest --watch" inside the project folder?

Note: Because you're using WSL you should check your bash configuration, your shell, and your $PATH environment variable.

Comment: 1. Jest is local to project.
2. same as running npm test
3. I'm not sure how to do that. It says jest isn't a valid program (see 1).

What should I check in my bash config/shell/$PATH?  Thanks